# Adding more rows to TableLayout from partial XML

Tags: java, android, xml

So I am trying to inflate a `TableLayout` with more rows in my java app.

Here is the code I am currently running:

```
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

        //The part that fails
        TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.toastTable);
        View row = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.toast_table_layout_row, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_row));
        table.addView(row);

        Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0 ,0);
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setView(layout);
        toast.show();
```

And here are my xml files:

toast_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/toast_layout_root"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:padding="8dp"
              android:background="#c3484848">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/toastTable"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:tag="toast_name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".50"
                android:text="Kultuur"
                android:textAllCaps="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:tag="toast_params"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".50"
                android:text="1000 tera mass g"
                android:textAllCaps="true"/>
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

toast_table_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:tag="toast_row"
    android:id="@+id/toast_row"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:tag="toast_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".50"
        android:text="Kultuur"
        android:textAllCaps="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:tag="toast_params"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".50"
        android:text="1000 tera mass g"
        android:textAllCaps="true"/>
</TableRow>
```

The idea is that I want to add more rows into my existing `TableLayout`
If I remove the code that is commented with `//The part that fails` then I get a toast that displays a `TableLayout` with a little bit of text in it.

But adding more rows fails with with a NullPointException.
I am not sure how it should be done correctly. End result should be that I add these rows in a loop and change their `TextField` text to something else by getting the `TextField` by the tag they have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have call findViewById() from the inflated view because your toastTable is in the toast_layout_root. just change

```
TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.toastTable);
```

to

```
TableLayout table = (TableLayout)layout.findViewById(R.id.toastTable);
```